# URL bookmark data when moved to trash

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I use `URL` `bookmark data` (with security scope). After a file was moved to the trash (presumably when the App was not running), the bookmark is updated. That is generally good, but when a file was moved to the trash, I really want to reflect that and remove my bookmark.

The only way I can think to get around it is to store the original `URL` and compare their `absoluteString` or check for `.Trash`.

Is there a (simple?) way to check that `bookmark data` is now pointing to the Trash?

Comment: This might help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47395827/1187415

Comment: @MartinR Sure does!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`FileManager` methods can be used if an URL refers to a file in a
trash, this avoids to hard-code the trash folder path. Here is
a translation of the Objective-C code in

- [Detect if file is in iCloudDrive Trash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46713307/detect-if-file-is-in-iclouddrive-trash/47395827#47395827)

to Swift, as an extension of `URL`:

```
extension URL {

    func inTrashFolder() -> Bool {
        do {
            let fm = FileManager.default
            let trashFolder = try fm.url(for: .trashDirectory, in: [], appropriateFor: self, create: false)
            var relationShip = FileManager.URLRelationship.other
            try fm.getRelationship(&relationShip, ofDirectoryAt: trashFolder, toItemAt: self)
            return relationShip == .contains
        } catch {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```